# Exit Code 0 but no output

Tags: python, output, new-operator, exit, scrape

I am new to python and coding in general. I found a code to scrape a website but whenever I run that code all I get is Exit Code 0 (I know that is good as it means there are not mistakes) but I do not get any output. Following the code I am using.

Does anyone have any ideas how to solve this ?

```
from collections import Counter
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def my_start(url):
   my_wordlist = []
   my_source_code = requests.get(url).text
   my_soup = BeautifulSoup(my_source_code, 'html.parser')
   for each_text in my_soup.findAll('div', {'class':'entry-content'}):
      content = each_text.text
      words = content.lower().split()
      for each_word in words:
         my_wordlist.append(each_word)
      clean_wordlist(my_wordlist)
# Function removes any unwanted symbols
def clean_wordlist(wordlist):
   clean_list =[]
   for word in wordlist:
      symbols = '!@#$%^&*()_-+={[}]|\;:"<>?/., '
      for i in range (0, len(symbols)):
         word = word.replace(symbols[i], '')
      if len(word) > 0:
         clean_list.append(word)
   create_dictionary(clean_list)
def create_dictionary(clean_list):
   word_count = {}
   for word in clean_list:
      if word in word_count:
         word_count[word] += 1
      else:
         word_count[word] = 1
   c = Counter(word_count)
   # returns the most occurring elements
   top = c.most_common(10)
   print(top)
# Driver code
if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_start("https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/python_overview.htm/")
```

Comment: You're printing out the very last step of thee entire process. Have you tried printing intermediates to make sure you're getting the expected output at various points?

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to search for a class `entry-content` but it seems that there is no class in your `HTML` you are getting from `URL`. Go to `URL` and inspect that page and find the class for which you are looking and update the line at below line in your code:

```py
for each_text in my_soup.findAll('div', {'class':'entry-content'}):
```

In your code, you never go inside this for loop, and the rest functions are not called.

Comment: Thank you very much. Changed it and now it works.

Comment: you are welcome. Can you accept this as the answer? you can see a write tik.

Answer (score 1):

I ran your code on my computer. The entire for loop (mentioned below) is not running.

```
   for each_text in my_soup.findAll('div', {'class':'entry-content'}):
```

This is because there is 'entry-content' div on that page and hence the rest of the functions are not called. The code works fine for other web URLs when I mentioned a div class that is there in the website's code.

Try debugging your code next time with a debugger or by using print statements. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you. Changed the class and now it is working